# Multiple selects with a single scan over an expensive table expression

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql, query-performance

How do I (efficiently) do multiple selects over an expensive table expression?

I have a table with a structure like this

```
CREATE TABLE facts (
    subject_id INT,
    visit_id INT,
    study_id INT,
    provider_id INT,
    variable_id INT,
    value TEXT
)
```

i.e. each row is a measurement that has a number of dimensions and a value. The `facts` table is large, but each dimension is much smaller, e.g. the cardinality of `SELECT DISTINCT subject_id FROM facts` could be a few hundred.

Now I want to find the unique dimension values for a subset of facts, i.e. the ids of the distinct subjects, visits, providers and variables for study_id = X. That is simple to query for by doing multiple queries as in

```
SELECT DISTINCT subject_id FROM facts WHERE study_id = X;
SELECT DISTINCT visit_id FROM facts WHERE study_id = X;
SELECT DISTINCT provider_id FROM facts WHERE study_id = X;
SELECT DISTINCT variable_id FROM facts WHERE study_id = X;
```

but each query then has to do a separate scan over the `facts` table (or an index). (The cardinality of `SELECT * FROM facts WHERE study_id = X` is also large, though not as large as the entire table.)

Is there some way to combine these queries so that the db only has to do one scan over the `facts` table and collect all the distinct dimension id's in one go?

So far I tried using a common table expression, but that still results (in Postgres) in multiple scans over the CTE so it doesn't help. e.g:

```
WITH selected AS (SELECT * FROM facts WHERE study_id = X)
SELECT DISTINCT subject_id, 1 FROM selected
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT visit_id, 2 FROM selected
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT provider_id, 3 FROM selected
UNION ALL SELECT DISTINCT variable_id, 4 FROM selected
```

Is there any way to have the DB only do a single scan over the `facts` and collect all needed results? I'm specifically interested in Postgres and Oracle support.

Comment: "*but that still results in multiple scans over the CTE*" of course it does as you select multiple times from it. The database **has** to scan that multiple times. But those "scans" will be done entirely in memory if the result of the select is small enough - if you need that as fast as possible, increase `work_mem` in Postgres. `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` will show you if that was done in memory or not.

Comment: `select array_agg(distinct subject_id) as subject_ids, array_agg(distinct visit_id) as visit_ids, ... from facts where study_id = x;` - it is for PostgreSQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The database doesn't have to scan multiple times if the optimizer were smart enough. The database is free to use any query strategy as long as it gives the correct answer. And in my case the CTE can still be too large to keep in memory depending on what else is going on at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This could be an approach in Oracle.

**setup:**

```
create table test(a, b, c) as (
    select  1,  2,  3 from dual union all
    select  1, 20, 30 from dual union all
    select  1,  2, 30 from dual union all
    select  1, 20, 30 from dual union all
    select 10,  2,  3 from dual union all
    select 10, 22,  3 from dual union all
    select  1, 20,  3 from dual
)
```

**query:**

```
select distinct column_name, column_value
from test
unpivot (column_value for column_name in  (a, b, c) )
```

**plan:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |      |    21 |   336 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH UNIQUE         |      |    21 |   336 |    10  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   VIEW               |      |    21 |   336 |     9   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    UNPIVOT           |      |       |       |            |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |     7 |   273 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("unpivot_view_006"."COLUMN_VALUE" IS NOT NULL)
```

**result:**

```
C COLUMN_VALUE
- ------------
B           22
C            3
C           30
A           10
A            1
B            2
B           20
```

I made the test with a very small table; here the plan shows a single full scan of the table, but followed by the unpivot and an hash unique.

For the same table, the solution with the `UNION` does:

```
select distinct a , 'a' from test union 
select distinct b , 'b' from test union 
select distinct c , 'c' from test

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |    21 |   273 |    12  (75)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE        |      |    21 |   273 |    12  (75)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   UNION-ALL         |      |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |     7 |    91 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |     7 |    91 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| TEST |     7 |    91 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```